# Rank vs. Distinct

Tags: oracle, distinct, rank

Just for curiosity, if I have to use `rank` to tag distinct values for some columns only, and ignore whatever different values occurred on other columns, why not use `distinct` and just remove the other columns? Any real life examples?

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
 col1,
 col2,
 col3,
 col4,
 row_number () over (partition by col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) RN
FROM table) tmp_table
WHERE rn = 1
```

vs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 col1,
 col2
FROM table
```

When ordered by `col3`, there is a chance you can get different values of `col3` compared to rank 2, right? Then if that `col3` is not important because it is not consistent, why not use `distinct` instead for only `col1` and `col2`?

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You are using ROW_NUMBER(), not RANK()
2. For the example you cite, it does not really make much difference
3. For other situations, ROW_NUMBER() provides additional flexibility. For example, suppose you are doing a data cleanse, and you want to read you input table and write all the duplicated rows into another table, so that you can process them further. Then you can do something like:

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into table2
select * from (
  select col1
        , col2
        , col3
        , col4
   row_number() over (partition by <key columns> order by <xxx> ) rn
   from table )
where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

> When ordered by `col3`, there is a chance you can get different values of `col3` compared to rank 2, right?

Yes, if  I understand correctly what you are asking.

> Then if that `col3` is not important because it is not consistent, why not use `distinct` instead for only `col1` and `col2`?

The difference between query 1 and 2 and is that query 1 returns more information than 2. It includes columns `col3` and `col4` in the output.

While query-2 returns all the distinct values of col1 and col2, query-1 returns all the distinct values of col1 and col2 plus the values of col3 and col4 from the first row (ordered by col3) of each group (ie. each col1 + col2 combination).

> Just for curiosity, if I have to use rank to tag distinct values for some columns only, and ignore whatever different values occurred on other columns, why not use distinct and just remove the other columns?

Yes, if you don't need the rest of the columns, but only col1 and col2, there is no difference.